# "With whom who" vs "Who with whom", a split preposition, and a phrase request for a seemingly strange way of dating among some teenagers

Tags: prepositions, phrase-request, colloquial-language

Context:

Pete likes Jane and Anne. His friend Jack (all the four in their early teens), too, likes both the girls who, in their turns, like both the boys.  To get sure which of the two possible pairs should date on on a permanent basis, Jack and Pete, and Jane and Anne as well, agreed to try changing their dates once in a while. A mutual friend of theirs, Tom, guessing the situation rather than knowing about the agreement, after the boys told him that they just went to watch the same movie in different places, wants to ask who went there with whom.

The variants of the question that I was able to think of are as they follow:

> With whom who went to the movies this time?
>
> Who with whom went to the movies this time?
>
> Who of the two *with* did you go to the movies this time?
>
> Who of the two did you go to the movies *with* this time?

My question is about the most casual question that Tom might ask to get the information he wants to get, like, "I (me), with Anne. Jack, with Jane."  Are there any English expressions to describe the experiment carried out by the teens in the context? What can be said in short in colloquial English about their maybe strange yet somewhat rational way of dating?

Comment: *"Who went to the movies with who?"* is what I would ask. Although I personally don't use "whom", *"Who went with **whom**?"* is also fine.

Comment: @Andrew - I would accept this were it posted in the answer-box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it may sound slightly formal (although not too much for a well-spoken teenager), I would ask:

> Who went to the movies **with who**?

BrE speakers (and a good number of AmE speakers) seem to prefer "whom":

> Who went with **whom**?

This can be used with almost any action:

> **A**:  So I was going to drive with Ann, but she said she wanted to go with Bill, but then Charlie came along and said he could take all of us, but Dave wanted to go with Edna, and then ...
>
> **B**:  Wait.  I'm confused.  **Who drove with whom?**

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason that Tom has to perform linguistic cartwheels in order to address both Jack and Pete at the same time.

> Anne: Hey Pete, I had fun last night. See you around.
>
> Pete: Yeah, me too, bye.
>
> Tom: Wait! So, Pete, who did you go out with? 'Cause I thought you were seeing Jane.
>
> Jack: No, I went out with Jane.
>
> Pete: Yeah, we swapped, just for the evening.
>
> Tom: So you went out with Anne then, Pete.
>
> Pete: Yeah, it was fun.

and so on and so on. Because that's how conversations work.

In general, if you feel tempted to make a question with two question pronouns, split it into two questions.

Don't say:

> How did you eat the what?

Do say

> What did you eat? And how did you eat it?

or

> Who did Jack go to the movies with? And who did Pete take?